# Typing FormData request on Express Request generic

Tags: express, form-data

I am sending a FormData object like the one from down below from my client to Express API:

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append("file", File);
form.append(
   "project", string>
);
```

On the express route, `Multer` is used to parse `file` field to `req.fields` and `project` field to `req.body`. Everything works, except I don't know how to type the Request generic so that it knows `req.fields` will be populated with the `file` and `req.body` with `project` property.

Currently, the request itself is typed with (since I am reusing the request DTO types on the client and the API):

```
type FormFields = "project" | "file";

export interface RequestDto extends FormData {
  append(name: FormFields, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
}
```

And the request on the Express route is typed like this:

```
Request<unknown, undefined, RequestDto>
```

But this does not work as needed.

Any advice is welcomed. Thanks